# How to test whether component with specific name is registered in Composition API (Vue 3)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a template loading dynamic components via their name:

```html
<template>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <component
              :is="getFormRenderer"
            ></component>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</template>
```

`getFormRenderer`returns a string (it comes from an API) that identifies the component by name.

All possible sub-components (in this example only `telegram_send_message` and `time_time` are imported and registered:

```html
<script>
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { computed } from "vue";

import exampleComponentOne from "@/components/forms/exampleComponentOne.vue";
import exampleComponentTwo from "@/components/forms/exampleComponentTwo.vue";
import defaultComponentTwo from "@/components/forms/defaultComponent.vue";

export default {
  name: "ActionEditor",
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();

    const getFormRenderer = computed(() => {
      return (
        store.state.level.actionSelected.plugin
      );
    });
    return {
      getFormRenderer,
    };
  },
  components: {
    exampleComponentOne,
    exampleComponentTwo,
    defaultComponent
  },
};
</script>
```

Now I want to modify the  dynamic `<component>` in a way that it defaults to `defaultComponent.vue` if the getFormRenderer returns a component name that does not exist.

But I can't find any way to realize this. I thought of using this.hasOwnProperty() but inside of the setup() this does is undefined.

Is there a standard way to do that?

Comment: You can setup the defaultComponent in the getFormRenderer if the plugin is not support ed or null

Comment: yes. i thought that too, but how could I check for the plugin being null? I found no way so far to check from within setup() if a component has been registered or not. Or would you do that another way than checking for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple way to check whether a component exists in `setup()` is to use [`resolveComponent()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#resolvecomponent) or [`resolveDynamicComponent()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#resolvedynamiccomponent), which looks up a component by name. Note the docs for `resolveDynamicComponent()` state that it raises a warning for nonexistent components, but it's actually `resolveComponent()` that does that (as of `v3.0.9`).

Both functions return the given component name if the component is not found, so you could determine whether the component exists by verifying the return type is not a string:

```js
import { computed, resolveDynamicComponent } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const isComponent = name => typeof resolveDynamicComponent(name) !== 'string'

    const store = useStore();
    const getFormRenderer = computed(() => 
      isComponent(store.state.level.actionSelected.plugin)
        ? store.state.level.actionSelected.plugin
        : 'DefaultComponent'
    );

    return {
      getFormRenderer
    }
  },
  components: {
    //...
  },
}
```

[demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 4):

To test whether component with specific name is registered globally in the app you can use [app.component()](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#component) function passing only first argument (component name)

To do that in any component in your app, you can use a (rather sparsely documented) function [getCurrentInstance](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance) - this function can be called only inside `setup` or hooks and you can use it's return value to test if component is registered

1. For global components use `getCurrentInstance().appContext.app.component()` function (where `appContext.app` property represents main `app` object created with `createApp()`)
2. For locally registered components use `getCurrentInstance().components['name']`

See the example bellow for global components (note that example is using Vue from CDN so it is using global Vue object. In normal development you use imports instead - for example `import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'`)

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({})

app.component('mainComponent', {
  template: `
    <component :is="getComp1OrDefault"></component>
    <component :is="getComp2OrDefault"></component>
  `,
  setup() {  
    const vm =  Vue.getCurrentInstance()
    //console.log(vm) 
    const getComp1OrDefault = Vue.computed(() => {
      return vm.appContext.app.component('comp1') ? 'comp1' : `defaultComp`
    });
    
    const getComp2OrDefault = Vue.computed(() => {
      return vm.appContext.app.component('comp2') ? 'comp2' : `defaultComp`
    });
    
    return {
      getComp1OrDefault,
      getComp2OrDefault
    };
  }
})

app.component('comp1', {
  template: `<div>Comp1</div>`
})

app.component('defaultComp', {
  template: `<div>defaultComp</div>`
})

app.mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.7/vue.global.js" integrity="sha512-+i5dAv2T8IUOP7oRl2iqlAErpjtBOkNtREnW/Te+4VgQ52h4tAY5biFFQJmF03jVDWU4R7l47BwV8H6qQ+/MfA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="app">
  <main-component />
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `getCurrentInstance()` is an internal API that was accidentally documented (it has been removed from the docs now). More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209080/vue-3-is-getcurrentinstance-deprecated