# Detect in Vue Component if it's used in Nuxt 3 or somewhere else

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I had this component for example in my UI library, that detected if it ran in Nuxt 2 using the "nuxt" property, but this does not work in Nuxt 3 anymore.

```html
<template>
  <nuxt-link v-if="nuxt && to" :to="to" class="base-button button-primary" :disabled="disabled">
    <slot/>
  </nuxt-link>
  <router-link v-else-if="!nuxt && to" :to="to" class="base-button" :disabled="disabled">
    <slot/>
  </router-link>
  <button v-else type="button" @click="$emit('click')" class="base-button" :disabled="disabled">
    <slot/>
  </button>
</template>
```

Is there any chance to detect from a Vue component, if it runs in a Nuxt 3 app or somewhere else?

Comment: You can use [resolveComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66878909/4254681) to check if it is registered and show the correct component

Comment: @Duannx unfortunately if this is an external library, resolveComponent() will run in the library context and not find nuxt-link.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Finding myself in the same frustrating situation.

Comment: Still no clue how to solve it. Especially SSR makes it even more difficult, because you don't even have the window object where the `__NUXT__` object would be detectable

Comment: I've added it as a feature proposal to Nuxt's GitHub https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/19698

Comment: @MarianKlühspies How is your library able to resolve nuxt-link, I am trying to do the same thing and even with the v-if vue is complaining.

Comment: @JulienBreuil not sure what you mean. If you use the nuxt.com framework, the component is provided by the framework, otherwise, it's just an unknown HTML tag behaving like a div

Comment: @MarianKlühspies I guess I must have some weird setup because with a code similar to yours I endup with a vue warning Failed to resolve component: NuxtLink even in a nuxt context. This only triggers with the component imported from the library, nuxtlink is working as expected otherwise. Did you declare nuxt-link as a custom element in your library config or something?

Comment: @JulienBreuil not that I know. But both projects are sitting in a monorepo with a top-level tsconfig, in case it might make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pi0 from the Nuxt community answered my feature request on** GitHubhttps://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/19698#issuecomment-1469823282

> You can directly use tiny unctx library in your integrations and this
> way detect existence of nuxt context:

```
import { useContext } from 'unctx'

const isNuxt = () => !!useContext('nuxt-app')
```

I've tested it and it works for me.